# What is the difference between --fields-terminated-by and--input-fields-terminated-by

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

What is the difference between --fields-terminated-by and--input-fields-terminated-by. Both are used in IMPORT tool in apache document. Not finding any example for --input-fields-terminated-by. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

--input-fields-terminated-by is used for sqoop Export.